# Magento: count product images and update attribute

Tags: php, magento, count, attributes, magento-1.9

I want to count the images of each product and save/update the value in the attribute imagecount.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('app/Mage.php'); // this is assuming your script is located in the Magento root dir
Mage::app(); // initiate the Magento engine

$allProductIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $allProductIds));

foreach ($products as $product) {

    $product->getGalleryImages();
    $pimagecount = count($product);
    echo count($pimagecount);
    $product->setImagecount($pimagecount);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'imagecount');
}
```

I tried to get the values with the code above but the output is always 1 for each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('app/Mage.php'); // this is assuming your script is located in the Magento root dir
Mage::app(); // initiate the Magento engine

$allProductIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $allProductIds));

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId());
    $gi = $product->getGalleryImages();
    $product->setImagecount(count($gi));
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code can you please check again with this code.

Comment: Now there is no number displayed. Where is count function? It's impossible to get the number of images without it I think.

Comment: @Rob I have updated my answer with the `$product->setImagecount(count($gi));` sorry for hassle.

Comment: Great! This works fine, thank you! Additionally do you know what I have to add regarding storeviews if I want to display the number global in all stores? Now only the store with id 1 get the imagecount number.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' in /html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /html/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):  ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like below:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('app/Mage.php'); // this is assuming your script is located in      the Magento root dir
Mage::app(); // initiate the Magento engine


$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($products as $product) {
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$images = $product->getData('media_gallery');
$pimagecount = count($images['images']);
echo $pimagecount;
}
```